# paired data, two variables into contingency table

Tags: r

I have a paired data set with two categorical variables, one of which is ordered (year and extent)

```
ID    year     extent
A     2017     Not at all
B     2017     Partially
A     2013     Substantially
C     2017     Fully
B     2013     Not at all
C     2013     Partially
```

that I'd like converted into a contingency table to reflect the change in extent over time.

```
              2017
2013          Not At All Partially Substantially Fully
Not At All       0          1             0       0
Partially        0          0             0       1
Substantially    1          0             0       0
Fully            0          0             0       0
```

I've tried converting the data into a frequency table and using xtabs but I'm not able to represent both variables in each column/row.

```
                  year
extent            2013 2017
Not at all           1    1
Partially            1    1
Substantially        1    0
Fully                0    1
```

I know I can manually create a matrix but my data set is much too large for this to be feasible. Any idea of a more efficient way this can be done?

Edit: I need 'extent' to remain ordered (Not at all, Partially, Substantially, Fully) to enable a further analysis.

Comment: `table(df$extent, df$year)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the levels and also the ordering:

```
table(lapply(unstack(dat,extent~year),factor,levels=unique(dat$extent)))
               X2017
X2013           Not at all Partially Substantially Fully
  Not at all             0         1             0     0
  Partially              0         0             0     1
  Substantially          1         0             0     0
  Fully                  0         0             0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do filter to select before apply `table`

```
table(df$extent[df$year==2017],df$extent[df$year==2013])

                Fully Notatall Partially Substantially
  Fully             0        0         1             0
  Notatall          0        0         0             1
  Partially         0        1         0             0
  Substantially     0        0         0             0
```

Comment: Hi this works well but I forgot to add that I need extent to remain ordered rather than alphabetical.